# Shopify Liquid conditionally include sections

Tags: include, shopify, liquid, code-snippets

So the current Shopify implementation of sections leaves a lot to be desired. The majority of the functionality is relegated to the homepage.

I'm trying to skirt around that to a certain degree but basically chucking all the section functionality (that would normally be split into multiple sections) into *one* section file, and then duplicating it for each product in the store, reusing the handle of each product as the section name.

E.g.: `example-product-handle` --> `sections/example-product-handle.liquid`

My idea was then to create, in the main `product.liquid` file, a simple routing system that would conditionally include a section if one exists that matches with the handle. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15635547/3072442) got my creative juices flowing.

The ideal result would look like...

```
{% assign current_page = product.handle %}
{% capture snippet_exists %}{% section current_page %}{% endcapture %}
{% unless snippet_exists contains "Liquid error" %}
    {% section current_page %}
{% endunless %}
```

This works *beautifully* for snippets. Replace `section` with `include` in that code, and the routing system performs perfectly.

With sections however?

> Liquid syntax error: Error in tag 'section' - Valid syntax: section '[type]'

Is there no way around this? Do section names have to be explicitly stated?

Comment: I can't guide you how to make dynamic sections, but you can refer here - https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/theme-editor/sections#static-and-dynamic-sections

Comment: Dynamic section would be perfect, but the problem is this: "Sections can be dynamically added to the theme's homepage from the theme editor." They're only usable on the homepage. Elsewhere, you have to turn to static sections, whose contents are the same across each page they're included on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible. It is purposefully not possible. Try instead using the section to dynamically include snippets.

```
{% for block in section.blocks %}
  {% case block.type %}
  {% when 'layout1' %}
    {% include 'layout1' %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is useful to know. Thank you for providing an alternate solution. 
I'm curious: why is it purposely not possible to conditionally include a section.

Comment: @DylanKinnett My guess is because the sections are tied in with the theme customiser, conditionally hiding and showing portions of the theme customiser would be a bad user experience.